# lxd with own br0 Network is Unreachable in centos conteiner

Tags: bridge, lxc, lxd

When I run lxd init I choose this setting.

```
Would you like to create a new network bridge (yes/no)? no
```

because I created my own br0 in /etc/network/interfaces

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address x.x.50.2
    netmask 255.255.252.0
    broadcast x.x.x.255
    network x.x.x.0
    gateway x.x.53.254
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0

iface eth0 inet manual
```

Then I launch lxd centos and run

```
 lxc config device add first eth0 nic nictype=bridged parent=br0
 lxc config device set first eth0 ipv4.address x.x.51.2
 lxc config device set first eth0 security.mac_filtering true
```

and change configuration in

```
 /var/lib/lxd/containers/second/rootfs/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

 DEVICE=eth0
 BOOTPROTO=none
 ONBOOT=yes
 HOSTNAME=LXC_NAME
 NM_CONTROLLED=no
 TYPE=Ethernet
 IPADDR=x.x.51.2
 NETMASK=255.255.255.255
 GATEWAY=x.x.53.254
 DNS1=8.8.8.8
 DNS2=x.x.x.x
 MTU=
 DHCP_HOSTNAME=x.x.50.2
```

When I try ping 8.8.8.8 I get  Connection: Network is Unreachable

/etc/resolv.conf

```
 nameserver 8.8.8.8
 search lxd
 nameserver x.x.x.x
```

What am I doing wrong I cannot figure out, maybe I'm missing some conception?